# Salesforce Mobile not selecting correct picklist values

Tags: angularjs, salesforce

I am experiencing a weird problem. I have created a "Mobile Call Report" Form in Salesforce. This form can be accessed via the browser as well as the Salesforce1 App via your mobile device. Recently I added two picklist dropdown menues to this form. When I view this form(and the picklist menu) in my browser, everything looks and works great. But the weird thing is, when I view it in my mobile app, I select a value from the picklist, it selects the value one below what I selected. Then I will go ahead tap anywhere on the form and then it ends up selecting what I actually chose. Has anyone experienced anything like this before. I have added some snippets of my Angular code below. If anyone needs to see any backend APEX classes, I can add some of that as well. Thank you

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false" docType="html-5.0" 
            applyHtmlTag="false"
            applyBodyTag="false"> 
<head> 

<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta name="description" content=""/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"/>

<apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.sf1MobilePackDist,'sf1MobilePackDist/css/bootstrap-namespaced.css')}"/>
<apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.sf1MobilePackDist,'sf1MobilePackDist/css/docs.min.css')}"/>

<apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.s1styles_css)}"/>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="internalAttendeeTypeAheadSearch.html">
  <a> 
      <span bind-html-unsafe="match.label | typeaheadHighlight:query"></span><br/>
      <span bind-html-unsafe="match.model.User__r.Department"></span>
  </a>
</script>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="distTypeAheadSearch.html">
  <a> 
      <span bind-html-unsafe="match.label | typeaheadHighlight:query"></span><br/>
  </a>
</script>


<script  type="text/ng-template" id="errorTemplate">

</script>


</head>
<body>

<div class="bootstrap-sf1" ng-class="overflow"> 

  <!-- 2. actual template place holder --> 


<div id="header" class="page-header page-header-anchor">
  <table style="width: 100%;" >
      <thead>
        <col style="width:20%" />
        <col style="width:80%" />
       </thead>
       <tr>
        <td>
            <span ng-show="screen=='CALLREPORT' || screen=='PAV'"  class="s1icon s1icon-m s1icon-s-case-log-a-call"></span>
        </td> 
        <td style="text-align:left; padding-left:10px;">
            <h3 ng-show="screen=='CALLREPORT'" >New Call Report</h3>
            <h3 ng-show="screen=='PAV'" >Planned Agency Visits</h3>
            <h3 ng-show="screen=='NEWCONTACT'" >Create New Contact</h3>
        </td>
        </tr>
       <tr>
          <td colspan="2">
              <h4>{{callReport.Agency__r.Name}}</h4>
              <p style="font-size:8pt;">{{callReport.Agency__r.Owner_Master__c}} <span ng-bind-html="bullet"></span>  {{callReport.Agency__r.Sub_Stat__c}} (sub) <span ng-bind-html="bullet"></span>  {{callReport.Agency__r.BillingCity}}</p>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table> 
</div> <!--  end of page header  -->
<div ng-show="CallReportDetailTabActive" ng-click="handleCallReportDetailTabClick($event)" > 
 <form name="callreportForm" id="callreportFormId" class="form-horizontal" novalidate="true" role="form" >
 <div class="card-list">
     <div class="card"> <!-- new card -->
        <div class="card-heading">Date of Call<sup>*</sup></div>
        <ul class="card-detail ">
          <li>
          <input type="text" class="sf1inputdate" datepicker-popup="MM/dd/yyyy" readonly="readonly" 
                                                ng-model="callReport.Date_of_Call__c"  is-open="calendaropened" 
                                                datepicker-options="calendarOptions"  ng-required="true" />

          </li>
        </ul>    
      </div> <!-- end card -->

       <div class="card"> <!-- new card -->
        <div class="card-heading">Agency Interaction Type<sup>*</sup></div>
        <ul class="card-detail ">
          <li>
           <select  class="sf1select" 
                    ng-model="callReport.Agency_Touch_Point__c" 
                    ng-options="t.value as t.name for t in agencytouchpoints"  ng-required="true"/>
         </li>
        </ul>
      </div> <!-- end card -->  

      <div class="card"> <!-- new card -->
        <div class="card-heading">Discussion Points</div>
        <ul class="card-detail ">
          <li>
           <select id="discussionPointsSelect" 
                    class="sf1selectmultiple" multiple="multiple" 
                    ng-model="callReport.Discussion_Points__c" 
                    ng-options="d.value as d.name for d in discussPointLst" />
         </li>
        </ul>
      </div> <!-- end card -->  

        <div class="card"> <!-- new card -->
        <div class="card-heading">Report Focus</div>
        <ul class="card-detail ">
          <li>
            <select  class="sf1select"   
                    id="reportFocusSelect"
                    ng-model="callReport.Report_Focus__c" 
                    ng-change="changeDiscussionPointPicklist()"
                    ng-options="f.value as f.name for f in focusoptions" />
         </li>
        </ul>
      </div> <!-- end card -->

       <div class="card"> <!-- new card -->
        <div class="card-heading">Related Notifications</div>
        <ul class="card-detail ">
          <li>
           <select id="relatedAlertsSelect" 
                    class="sf1selectmultiple" multiple="multiple" 
                    ng-model="callReport.Related_Notifications__c"  
                    ng-options="d.value as d.name for d in myNotificationForAgencyPickList" />
         </li>
        </ul>
      </div> <!-- end card -->  
 <!--New picklist fields that I added is below-->



      <div class="card"> <!-- new card -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <div class="card-heading">Time Spent at Agency Visit/Call<sup>*</sup></div>
                <ul class="card-detail ">
                    <li>
                        <select  class="sf1select"   
                            id="reportFocusSelect"
                            ng-model="callReport.Duration_of_Visit_Call_mins__c" 
                            ng-change="changeDiscussionPointPicklist()"
                            ng-options="t.value as t.name for t in timeoptions" ng-required="true"/>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <div class="card-heading">Time Spent in Transit to Agency</div>
                <ul class="card-detail ">
                    <li>
                        <select  class="sf1select"   
                            id="reportFocusSelect"
                            ng-model="callReport.Transit_to_Agency__c" 
                            ng-change="changeDiscussionPointPicklist()"
                            ng-options="t.value as t.name for t in transitoptions"/>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div> <!-- end card -->
```